# Weights for $sl_{2}(\mathbb{C})$-irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $L=sl_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ be the special linear Lie algebra with basis $e,f,h$;

Let $V_{n}$ be its irreducible $(n+1)$-dimensional representation;

Finally let $Hom(V_{m},V_{n})\cong V^{*}_{m}\otimes V_{n}$ and assume $m\geq n$.

Describe the $h$-weights of  $Hom(V_{m},V_{n})$ and count the dimension of the weight spaces, for weights $l\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $m − n \leq l \leq m + n$.

I think that we can suppose to take a basis $(v_{0},...,v_{m})$ of $V_{m}$ seeing $V_{n}\subset V_{m}$ with basis $(v_{o},...,v_{n})$;

Now we know $h.v_{j}=(\lambda-2j)v_{j}$ and using the induced action on $V_{m}^{*}$ and after on $V_{m}^{*}\otimes V_{n}$ I get that the weights are of the form $2(k-j)$ with $0\leq k\leq m$ and $0\leq j\leq n$.

Maybe all its wrong and I appreciate some suggestion to how to find these weights;

Thanks very much!

Comment: If you try to think of $V_n$ as a subspace of $V_m$ you will come to a lot of grief. The $L$-actions are incompatible. Instead, you need a dual basis $v_i', 0\le i\le m,$ for a weight vector basis of $V_m$, and a totally unrelated basis $u_j, 0\le j\le n$ of weight vectors of $V_n$, and then check what happens when $L$ acts on vectors like $v_i'\otimes u_j$ (and linear combinations of such vectors).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Actually, rather than take a dual basis here, one can just use that simple finite dimensional $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-modules are self-dual.

Comment: Correct, of course, @Tobias. However, there is a fair chance that this exercise is encountered before they have covered self-duality of irreducible f.d. reps of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen They may not have seen it explicitly, but it is implicit in the term *the* $(n+1)$-dimensional irrep.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I try to explore your suggestion: I have to study the $h$-action on $V_{m}^{*}\otimes V_{n}$, so I have to study $h.(v_{i}'\otimes u_{j})=h.v_{i}'\otimes u_{j} +v_{i}'\otimes h.u_{j}=(\lambda-2i)v_{i}'\otimes u_{j} +v_{i}'\otimes (\mu-2j)u_{j}=(\lambda+\mu-2i-2j)v_{i}'\otimes v{j}$. But now $\lambda=\mu$? and all the expression: $(\lambda+\mu-2i-2j)$ are the weights?

Comment: Maybe since $dim V_{m}=m+1$ and $dim V_{n}=n+1$ then $\lambda=m,\mu=n$; so that the weights are: $(m+n-2i-2j)$. But how I count now the dimension of the weight spaces? we don't know that the dimension is always 1 ?

Comment: Maybe one can say this: the condition $m-n\leq m+n-2(i+j)\leq m+n$ forces $0\leq i+j\leq n$; now if $i+j=k$, the dimension of the weight space of weight $m+n-2k$ is $k+1$ since we have $k+1$ indipendent vector in $Hom(V_{m},V_{n})$ of weight $m+n-2k$, corresponding to the pairs $(i,j)$ with $i+j=k$; it is right?

Comment: Yes. That sounds familiar and also correct :-)

Comment: Perfect! :) ..thanks a lot!!